# How to change Windows default language to another language, but temporarily?

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, input-device

How to change Windows default language temporarily? For example, English to Russian, but for some time and without losing anything. I will revert back to English.

I want to change Language settings everywhere. In programs, Keyboard input, browsers etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7, you [must have the Ultimate](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/win7_skus_compare.asp#enterprise) (or Enterprise) version to change the language. This can be done from: `Control Panel` > `Clock, Language, and Region` > `Change display language`.

Comment: if i change language will it heart to anything upon revert, to any software, system settings etc

Comment: @metal I'm not sure what you mean, but changing the display language (and changing it back again) shouldn't affect the computer in any other way.

Comment: You might need to install the laguage package in Windows Updates first.

You can switch languages back and forth without any issues both in Windows 7 and Windows 8.