# How do I install a language pack in Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, input-languages, korean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change Windows default language to another language, but temporarily?](https://superuser.com/questions/146713/how-to-change-windows-default-language-to-another-language-but-temporarily)

Specifically, I want Korean ([link](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/updt/2009/08/windows6.1-kb972813-x64-ko-kr_e6b3322c3865cfd328d84376e192c4f9d41aa0e6.exe)), but I hope this helps other people in general. According to [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813), it is only possible for Ultimate and Enterprise. Specifically, I'd like to enable my keyboard to type in Korean, and I specified Korean as the input language (Start -> type "Input Languages", only result). Under the General tab, I selected Add, and specified Korean.. but it doesn't work, because the language pack isn't installed I presume. Would anyone know how to add different language input / packs to Windows 7 Home Premium?

Also, I tried following [this tutorial](http://www.wincert.net/tips/microsoft-windows/windows-7/2086-how-to-use-another-language-pack-on-windows-7-home-premium-and-professional) on adding a language pack to HP, but the .cab keeps disappearing so it will not work.

Note: Unlike the link in the tutorial as well, I do not have an option to change the display language of Windows, only the option to change input methods.

Comment: What was the original language? AFAIK, MS only lets you add English to non-Enterprise/non-Ultimate editions

Comment: [Edit](http://superuser.com/posts/514933/edit) your question to add that information

Comment: It's legally not possible with Win7HP. You may buy another language version and reinstall. As for input methods use IME keyboard as in here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wit/archive/2009/01/14/how-to-use-microsoft-ime-to-input-east-asian-characters.aspx

Comment: @week Do you have a reference saying it is not legally possibly?

Comment: this is not supported. Using the linked tool makes Windows non genuine.

Comment: Its not possible.  As indicated by the very link you provided its only supported in Ultimate and Enterprise editions of Windows 7.

Comment: Duplicates may stay to function as anchors for searches. Don't worry about this question sticking around, it points to the "original" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify this.

You want to be able to use Korean as Input. But you are asking to install a Language Pack.

Language Pack in Windows 7 Home Premium: not possible.

Korean as input: it should work. The problem is NOT a missing language pack.

Have you got at the least the Language Bar being displayed?

Try [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12578/add-keyboard-languages-to-xp-vista-and-windows-7/).